# CSS adjust width of three fields on a form

Tags: html, css

Please suggest on making these div's aligned. First Name and last name on one line. Adjusting the width of all these 3 fields

```
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div class="Userbox">           
       <div class="UserNameDiv">
        <strong>Username</strong>
       <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
     </div>
      <div class="UserNameDiv" > 
        <strong>First Name</strong>
        <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <strong>Last Name</strong>
       <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>     
   </div>
     <div  id="EmailAddress">
      <strong>Email</strong>
      <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </div>

             </div>
        </form>
```

CSS

```
.Userbox
{

    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #0BA84D;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left:10%;
    align-self:center;
}

label.firstname {
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  }
 label.lastname {
  width: 150px;
  }
.EmailAddress {
    float:left;
}
#UserNameDiv {
    float:left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer to do this in table structure, to have a good format.  With less CSS.

Comment: ok, Could you please post an example. I know there is a lot on the internet. There is too much actually. Some small example would greatly help

Comment: Table structure is a good way to align your elements and it is works in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a good format, I prefer to use **tabular structure** like this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' />
            </td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' />
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

[image]

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5Zbj/2/)

Hope you got an idea to do this in ASP.

Comment: One mor question, Can I align these td's so that, username width = firstname+lastname.... I think something with colspan

Comment: @user575219 Yup, you can do it with `colspan`.  However you have to specify the `width` of `textbox` to 100%.  Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h5Zbj/4/